# the code coverage of my test class is 100% in the sandbox, but show 12% in the production

Tags: apex

problem is that the code coverage of my test class is 100% in the sandbox, but show 12% in the production.

my apex class and test class is as follows respectively

```
global with sharing class REST_Product_Controller {

    global static List<Product2> getProductInfo() { 

        List<Product2> result = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id='01t370000003LRX'];

        return result;

    }

}
```

test class:

```
@isTest 

public class REST_Product_Controller_Test {

    static testMethod void testgetProductInfo(){ 

        Test.startTest();

        REST_Product_Controller.getProductInfo();

        Test.stopTest();

        List<Product2> result = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id='01t370000003LRX'];

        Database.upsert(result,false);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably due to the fact that the test is reliant on the record with ID `01t370000003LRX` existing in the environment.  You should avoid this ([see official docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)) by setting up all test data within the test itself.

Your test also lacks assertions, which defeats the purpose of having the test in the first place.

You may find the [Apex Testing Trailhead Path](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/apex_testing) helpful to gain a better understanding of how to write tests on the platform.

Comment: Good catch. I was assuming the code would be of higher quality so the problem must be somewhere else =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some tests in your sandbox that contribute to that additional coverage and you dont have them in your production?

Comment: Or more specifically that test is not in production as, on its face, would cover it 100%